# Overloading new operator: How the size will be passed?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I have one doubt with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
void * operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout << "New operator overloading " <<"\n";
    void * p = malloc(size);
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void * p)
{
    cout << "Delete operator overloading " <<"\n";
    free(p);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3, i;
    int * p = new int[3];

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    p[i]= i;

    cout << "Array: ";
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    cout << p[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    delete p;
}
```

How will the size of `int[3]` be passed as the parameter to `void * operator new(size_t size)`?

See the following code, this will not work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sizef(size_t n)
{
    cout<<n;
}

int main()
{
    sizef(int[5]);
}
```

Please explain how this works.

Comment: Check the signatures here (I think you need the array ones as well; specifically (2) and the corresponding operator delete ): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: It won't in your case.   When allocating an array, the compiler generates a call of `operator new[]()`, not `operator new()`.   Either way, since the compiler has visibility of the new expression, it knows what is being allocated and the size required, so passes that to whichever allocation function it chooses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard [expr.new] [reads](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#10):

> A *new-expression* may obtain storage for the object by calling an allocation function. ... If the allocated type is an array type, the allocation function's name is `operator new[]` and the deallocation function's name is `operator delete[].` ... A C++ program can provide alternative definitions of these functions and/or class-specific versions.

[and](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#19) <sup>1</sup>:

> `new T[5]` results in one of the following calls:
>
> - `operator new[](sizeof(T) * 5 + x)`
> - `operator new[](sizeof(T) * 5 + x, std::align_val_t(alignof(T)))`
>
> Here, each instance of `x` is a non-negative unspecified value representing array allocation overhead; the result of the *new-expression* will be offset by this amount from the value returned by `operator new[]`. ... The amount of overhead may vary from one invocation of `new` to another.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that `operator new[]` allocates the storage, it does not construct objects. Object construction and initialization is another part of the job performed by `new`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does the size calculation for the `new` operator, and for the `new` operator only. It's not something generic for `size_t` arguments.